# Avoid defining service multiple times in Symfony 2 Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have multiple functions in my controller, and lots of them call `$usermgr = $this->get('usermanager');` (where usermanager is a service defined in config.yml).

This means code is repeated multiple times. Is there a way to define $usermgr only once in the controller? Normally I'd consider a __construct but I believe thats not possible with a controller?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with getting the same service in multiple methods in a controller.

You can change your controller into a service ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html and http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/04/15/symfony2-controller-as-service/ ) and then inject that service. While that follows the best practises, your current way is not wrong.

You cannot request that service in the constructor, using the Symfony base `Controller` class, as the service container is set after initialization.